# using array_unique in php codeigniter the returing only one value

Tags: php, codeigniter

If using array_unique in php codeigniter, it returns only on value. please give an guideline to solve the issue, I'm new to programming. I'm code is below.

```
Controllers    
function get_rck_detail()
{
$partnumber = $this->input->post('part_number');
$subbrand = $this->input->post('subbrand');
$part = $this->suggest->get_part_code($partnumber);
$rack_list = $this->suggest->get_rack_details($part,$subbrand);
echo '<option>--Location--</option>';
foreach(array_unique($rack_list) as $rack)
{

echo '<option value="'.$rack['rs_loc'].'">'.$rack['rack_name'].'</option>';
}
}
```

models

```
function get_rack_details($part,$subbrand)
 {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('rack_spares');
$this->db->join('rack_name','rack_spares.rs_loc = rack_name.rn_id');
$this->db->where('rs_product_code',$part);
$this->db->where('rs_sub',$subbrand);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: $rack_list is not single dimensional array. It's two dimensional array.

Comment: how to use remove the duplicate entries for this multi dimension array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller,

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$rack_list = $this->suggest->get_rack_details($part,$subbrand);
$res = array();
foreach($rack_list as $r)
   $res[$r["rs_loc"]] = $r["rack_name"]; // removes duplicates as we are assigning for keys   
$res[""] = "---Location---";
echo form_dropdown("location",$res); // this will produce <select><option></option>...</select>
```

In your view file, Remove existing `<select>` as controller generating options with select

As per your expectation, to get only options run below loop in controller instead of form_dropdown

```
$ret_content = "";
foreach($res as $k => $v)
  $ret_content .="<option value='".$k."'>".$v."</option>";

echo $ret_content;
```

Comment: it's not generating the value

Comment: sorry its my mistake. Please check my updated answer:-)

Comment: thank you for response sir, but it's not generating the value

Comment: can you check my updated answer. Again i did typo error. remove $ infront of form_dropdown

Comment: Call to undefined function form_dropdown() msg is shown, i have an onchange event and dynamically generate that with different ids. can u please guide me how to get the value in option value only.

Comment: check my updated answer. You didn't load form helper.

Comment: Oh! sorry sir, i didn't load it because i use all of us only in html. now it's working fine. thank you, Can u please guide me  how to get the values in option value only.

Comment: if you want options only, then you have to do select manually. I mean you have to run another one for loop.

Comment: yes sir, i wrote the onchange event for this, bcz and also i want to filter another selection box based on this selected value.

Comment: Ok. I added another option also. Check my updated answer. If it is helpful, then dont forget to accept my answer. Bye

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique` compares elements as strings. All arrays are cast to the string `"Array"` and are therefore all equal in the eyes of `array_unique`.

Try passing `SORT_REGULAR` as the second parameter, this should compare the arrays as arrays, ie. returning them as equal if they have the same key/value pairs in the same order. You may need to `ksort` your arrays first.

Comment: yes i use it. but it's not working display all values

Comment: Are your arrays, in fact, unique? Or just the name?

Comment: it's not just a name, it's an array value of total row in database

Comment: What I'm asking is, are the rows *completely identical*?

Comment: yes sir, actually the output of array like  [0] => Array ([rs_id] => 21[rs_product_code] => PRD001[rs_sub_id] => 3[rs_sub] => BRUCE[rs_loc] => 1[rs_ser] => AA[rs_num] => 411[rck_quan] => 0[rs_created_date] => 2014-02-10 13:04:09[rn_id] => 1 [rack_name] => GODOWNS
        )